# Post Image as FormData sets content-type as text/plain;charset=UTF-8

Tags: react-native, xmlhttprequest, multipartform-data, content-type

I have a two part question.

1. `FormData()` is not setting correct `Content-Type` when sending image. How do i resolve it?
2. How to read image as binary instead of `base64` in `react-native`

I am trying to upload an image to the server in react-native.

With `react-native-image-picker` I am able to pick the image and get its `uri` ( even `base64` ).

I'm then creating a `FormData()` and posting it via `fetch` ( even tried with `axios` and `XMLHttpRequest` ). But the `content-type` is set to `text/plain;charset=UTF-8` and so `req.files` is `undefined`.

However, when I manually create an `XMLHttpRequest` request to  [send the image (shown in 'Dealing with Binary Data' section)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript), I am able to send the image. But the image data is encoded in `base64` and not in `binary`.

Code for `XMLHttpRequest` with `FormData`

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.addEventListener('load', res=>{console.log(res)} )
xhr.addEventListener('error', err=>{console.log(err)} )

xhr.open('POST', global.config.getServerAddress() + this.props.api);
xhr.setRequestHeader( 'Authorization', 'Bearer ' +  global.config.token )

const formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append( this.props.label, { name: this.props.label, type: type, fileName: uri.split('/').pop() });

xhr.send(formdata);
```

code for manual `XMLHttpRequest` request which works. But need to send the image data as `binary` instead of `base64`.

```
const boundary = "myboundary"
let data = ""
data += "--" + boundary + "\r\n"
data += 'content-disposition: form-data; '
// Define the name of the form data
      + 'name="' + this.props.label + '"; '
// Provide the real name of the file
      + 'filename="'     + uri.split('/').pop() + '"\r\n'
// And the MIME type of the file
data += 'Content-Type: ' + type + '\r\n'

// There's a blank line between the metadata and the data
data += '\r\n'

// Append the binary data to our body's request
data += `data:${type};base64,` + image + '\r\n'
data += "--" + boundary + "--"

var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest()

XHR.addEventListener('load', callbackConf.callback )

XHR.addEventListener('error', callbackConf.errorCallback )

XHR.open('POST', global.config.getServerAddress() + this.props.api )
XHR.setRequestHeader( 'Authorization', 'Bearer ' +  global.config.token )
XHR.setRequestHeader( 'Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + boundary )

XHR.send( data )
```

Comment: You need to pass a [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) or a [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) to [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) to do a binary upload

Answer (score -1):

For your first query try this (I used [this picker](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-image-picker)):

```
let photo = { uri: source.uri}
let formdata = new FormData();

formdata.append("description", 'my-image')
formdata.append("image", {uri: photo.uri, name: 'image.jpg', type: 'multipart/form-data'})


fetch('YOUR_URL',{
  method: 'post',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
  },
  body: formdata
  }).then(response => {
    console.log("image uploaded")
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  })  
});
```

Comment: If I put 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' in the header, I'll need to provide a boundary. Fetch is not updating the boundary and the server gives out an error saying no boundary found.

Comment: In react native its optimum way to send multipart. I am not sure about your server code !

Comment: The server code works because If I manually create a boundary and sent Content-type to multipart ( the second code ), it works. However, when I set Content-type to 'multipart/form-data' alone,, the server doesnt know the boundary of the data sent, so it gives out an error. I am facing a problem here because, the second code sends a base64 image data and not a binary file. The 1st approach is supposed to send a binary file, but since the Content-type header is not correct, the server is not able to parse it properly. I dont know why fetch is not setting the correct header..

Answer (score -2):

I did this via `fetch`, to append data to form data do:
`const data = new FormData();
 data.append('image', {
      uri: uri,
      type: 'image/jpeg',
      name: 'random.jpg'
 });
 data.append('idUser', this.state.idUser);`

To send just do:
`fetch(uriApi, {
     method: 'post',
     body: data
 }).then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) =>{console.log(responseJson)})`

Comment: I've already tried this and its not working for some reason. The content-type is being set to text/plain;charset=UTF-8.

Comment: strange..don't know why it does that.. maybe see this: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5308 has some of your problems and some solutions